# Enterprise mobile apps deployment: Ionic view OR app store

Tags: ionic-framework, deployment, ionic2, mdm

I use ionic to develop mobile apps for employees to use internally.   To deploy my apps, I am struggling in between using ionic deployment (https://docs.ionic.io/services/deploy/) or MAM/MDM deployment (through private App store).

From ionic's official site:

> Live deployments let you publish web assets such as HTML, JS, and CSS
>   directly to your users without going through the app store.

It seems like I should also deploy my apps through app stores if I want to publish any new functions that require cordova plug-ins (or add push notification?).

My question is: can I mix both methods together for deploying my mobile apps?  Will my users need to use "ionic view" to install their apps or let my company MAM (Mobile app management) to push the apps?  How about if I need to publish update versions for my apps? (should I use ionic view or MAM?)